# Cannot build flatpak-builder beacuse no appstream.compose?

Tags: flatpak, freedesktop.org, flatpak-builder

I cannot find `appstream.compose` module. It is needed for `flatpak-builder`:

```
$ meson setup _build                   (git)-[main]
$ meson install -C _build                   
The Meson build system
Version: 1.1.1
Source dir: /home/q/github/flatpak-builder
Build dir: /home/q/github/flatpak-builder/_build
Build type: native build
Project name: flatpak-builder
Project version: 1.3.4
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 10.2.0 "cc (PCLinuxOS 10.2.0-2pclos2020) 10.2.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.40
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program debugedit found: YES 5.0 (/usr/bin/debugedit)
Program appstreamcli found: YES 0.15.4 (/usr/bin/appstreamcli)

meson.build:45:23: ERROR: Command `/usr/bin/appstreamcli compose --help` failed with status 4.
```

The problem is that using the standard way of installing the `compose` module doesn't work:

```
$ sudo appstreamcli install org.freedesktop.appstream.compose

Unable to find component with ID 'org.freedesktop.appstream.compose'!
```

So how to install the `compose` module and build `flatpak-builder`?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, install AppStream compose with your distribution. For example, with Ubuntu or Debian:

```
apt-get install appstream-compose
```

Fedora:

```
dnf install appstream-compose
```

openSUSE:

```
zypper in AppStream-compose
```